# Can I tie in bathroom vents with turbine roof vents?

Tags: bathroom, venting

I want to vent my 2 bathroom fans into one of my roof
turbine vents.Can it be done and not pose a mold problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you did this then the roof vent would no longer be venting the attic space and would only vent the bathroom. This would likely lead to higher temperatures in your attic which could result in a lower level of comfort in your home and reduce the lifespan of your roof.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a contractor vent my upper bathroom through a roof turbine. He absolutely ensured me it would be OK. He draped the tubing over a truss and then to the turbine. It has a damper installed also. He said there would be no problem at all and also that there was a good flow of exhaust air.

Comment: Did he offer you a lifetime guarantee on the work, or is he going to charge you later to remove the mold that could form?